# Grep regex not working

Tags: grep, last

So I'm creating a simple grep command that gets only the last logged in people who's username starts with 161 and has 3 digits next to it:

```
last | grep "^161[0-9]{3}"
```

However it doesn't print anything even though it has these usernames on the list.
Whats even more weirder is if I do egrep instead of grep

```
last | egrep "^161[0-9]{3}"
```

The command works.

Can anyone explain what is the difference?

Comment: Basic versus extended regular expression: https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Comment: Note that while your expression would match `161444`, it would also match `1614444444444444`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As steeldriver  already pointed out, `grep` uses basic regular expressions whereas `grep -E` and `egrep` use extended regular expressions.

```
last | grep  '^161[0-9]\{3\}'
last | egrep '^161[0-9]{3}'
```